# Micro-blogging software used at intranet, and open-sourced, with file attachment

Tags: open-source, attachment, microblogging

Our company wants to build a message-sharing system in intranet, like twitter or facebook but with file attachment in order to share messages or files quickly.

I have surveyed some micro-blogging systems like below:

- Google Wave (discontinued)
- Sharetronix (not free for enterprise use)
- wordpress + p2 theme (not easy for user management)

Because that the sharing messages do not very important for our business,
we would like to build it like twitter, not forum-like systems.
Besides, if using CMS like Drupal or joomla, it's much fat for our purpose.

Is there any suggestion about this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A lot has changed since this question was asked, and it would be good to know what direction you went in.  I had the same problem and ended up building a service around it, http://www.collabinate.com.

Answer (score 2):

maybe a spin on [StatusNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StatusNet) might help solve your problem. I mention "spin" (read: modification) because you mentioned files.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @darkphoenix, status.net now allows for attachments and whatnot:
http://status.net/wiki/Attachments

I'm not sure what the real goal of this might be, but some chat programs would allow for file transfers.  Would be fairly light-weight, I imagine, but I have not looked into them.